# "user-select: element" workaround for Google Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am working on a gui tool where text boxes can be selected, dragged around and the contents edited. Think of text editing in a drawing program such as powerpoint. I've got some quite specific requirements around text selection. I need to make sure when text is selected in one of the boxes, that the selection doesn't expand to text in other neighbouring boxes.

The good news is there is a way to do this, the bad news is it is IE only, and I need to find a workaround for Chrome.

[user-select: element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

> Supported only in Internet Explorer. Enables selection to
>   start within the element; however, the selection will be contained by
>   the bounds of that element.

I'm guessing that a workaround will need to do something like listening for selectstart, and selectchange events, calling preventDefault(), and manipulating the selection object manually.

Any ideas appreciated ;)

**Update:** Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y8EA/) that mostly works. Bugs are, that I need to prevent Ctrl-A somehow, and selecting and releasing the mouse outside of the window makes other text temporarily unselectable. Not sure how to workaround these, anybody? Cue tumbleweed...

**HTML**

```
<div id="one" class="textbox">qwe qweqwe <b>werwesd ewrwer</b> fsdfdsrwe fdsfsdf erertre fsdfsdf</div>

<div id="two" class="textbox">dsgdfs dfgdsf dfgdfg dfgdfs <i>dfsgsdf</i> dfsgdfsg</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.textbox {          
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    width: 250px;           
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#one { left: 150px; top: 150px; }
#two { left: 450px; top: 250px; }
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup, false);

// While selecting disallow selection of other text.
function mousedown(event) {
    console.log('mousedown', event.target);         
    var current = findParentTextBox(event.target);
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('.textbox');
    for (var i = 0, textbox; textbox = list[i]; i++) {
        if (textbox != current) {
            textbox.style.webkitUserSelect = 'none';
        }
    }
}

// Once finished selecting allow all text to be selected again.
function mouseup(event) {
    console.log('mouseup', event.target);
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('.textbox');
    for (var i = 0, textbox; textbox = list[i]; i++) {
        textbox.style.webkitUserSelect = 'text';
    }
}

function findParentTextBox(node) {
    while (node != null) {
        if (node.className == 'textbox')
            return node;
        node = node.parent;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Edit:**

Filed a chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346533

Comment: Clever hack you found there. You could have put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it interferes with your other interaction needs (dragging needs testing), but iframes may work for you. They have the selection behaviour you want right out of the box (including select all). You have to fill them with javascript or from external sources.
Here's your jsfiddle with iframes (with js to create the iframes from the divs): 
http://jsfiddle.net/5y8EA/3/

For editable text, you can check the `contenteditable` attribute:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: That's a clever hack. Yes I'm aware about content editable. I'm not using it at the moment. Which means pretty much re-implementing it - this gives me a bit more control - but is a lot of work.

Comment: Looking at the bug you mention and filed, I noticed the selecting problems only happen on nested elements. Maybe you noticed that already, but might help you to know =) Is this just an unsolveable bug for you, or can we be more of help here? Or did the iframes solve your question for now?

Comment: Oops I didn't notice that. I think that is probably fixable. I am planning on using my hacky solution in the meantime, and hoping that user-select: element arrives in the next year or so. But feel free to make improvements on the fiddle.